Is low-energy effective $k \cdot p$ Hamiltonian $h(k)$ an example of spontaneous symmetry breaking?
I am recently reading a paper on nonlinear Hall effects. After deriving the conducitivity tensor, $\chi_{abcd}$, the authors then apply the theory to analyze a simple 2D Dirac model, whose Hamiltonian is expressed as $$h(\mathbf k) = w k_x \sigma_0 + v_x k_x \sigma_x + v_y k_y \sigma_y + \Delta \sigma_z.$$ This is an effective Hamiltonian, probably obtained by expanding a real lattice tighe-binding Hamiltonian $h(\mathbf k)$ around some high-symmetry point, like what we do for treating graphene $K$ point. The authors then carry out symmetry analysis, and claim that components which are odd in spatical indices, like $\chi_{xyyy}$ and $\chi_{yxxx}$ must vanish, because there exists a mirror symmetry, $$\sigma_x h(k_x,k_y) \sigma_x^{-1} = h(k_x,-k_y).$$
The above are backgrounds. It seems not possible to find the original lattice symmetry out of the effective Hamiltonian, because when one Taylor expands $h(\mathbf k)$, much information on symmetry gets lost.
My question: Is this an example of what we usually call "spontaneous symmetry breaking"? They share a few common key words, like low symmetry and low energy, but the latter is often mentioned when analyzing order parameters. Thanks!

But the symmetry is not broken... Also, spontaneous applied to symmetry breaking is a term with specific meaning in the domain of critical phenomena, which is not relevant here. Perhaps you could clarify the Q.


It seems not possible to find the original lattice symmetry out of the effective Hamiltonian, because when one Taylor expands $h(k)$, much information on symmetry gets lost.

Information loss, yes.  But the expanded Hamiltonian can only get more symmetric than the full lattice model as a result, because you have less information to tell things apart.  Before other people go into lengthy lectures of what SSB really means, I want to first emphasize that the original lattice symmetry is intact in this case.
